# Bulk Unziping Into Folders Path

Tags: linux, bash, unzip

I have Linux based server with domains:

```
domain1.com
   public_html
      archive1.zip
domain2.com
   public_html
      archive2.zip
domain3.com
   public_html
      archive3.zip
```

I'm trying to run unziping in the following way:

```
unzip */public_html/*.zip
```

It works perfectly for one domain (except the fact that it unzips in folder where I launch this command).

Is there any way for bulk unziping to get the following output:

```
domain1.com
   public_html
      archive1.zip
      content_of_archive1
domain2.com
   public_html
      archive2.zip
      content_of_archive2
domain3.com
   public_html
      archive3.zip
      content_of_archive3
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: `unzip  <zip_file> -d <directory>` would unzip to a specific directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for a for loop:

```
for archive in */public_html/*.zip; do
   unzip "$archive" -d "$( dirname "$archive" )"
done
```

PS: I was going to use `pushd` to move to the directory, but @Mihir provided the simpler solution with `-d` in their comment.

PPS: You don't need a script to run this - just type it verbatim at the bash prompt, newlines included. Or you can fold it into a one-liner:

```
for archive in */public_html/*.zip; do unzip "$archive" -d "$( dirname "$archive" )"; done
```

Either, the `bash` command history will let you come back to what you typed and modifier and/or rerun it as needed.

Comment: That will fail horribly if any of the names contain spaces.

Comment: Btw, would also like to mention, didn’t know about `dirname` command. Had been using `${BASH_SOURCE%/*}` for long. That would simplify my work now.

Comment: Thank you but how to launch this script, I have > meaning that statement is not closed or expecting parameters to add...

Comment: @Marc, save the script with any name. Execute it like `bash <script_name>`. Also, it is probably showing `>` cuz you may have used quotes somewhere while entering which are waiting to be closed.

Comment: @Mihir thank you, was on this step when you wrote)

Comment: bash unziper.sh
unziper.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'nziper.sh: line 2: `for archive in */public_html/*.zip; do

Comment: Okay, my fault, new line caused it.

Comment: @Marc thank you so much for your time and efforts, I just started this option and was eager to complete. Your solution is very good, I cannot thumb it up due to low reputation, unfortunately. I will use it next time for unziping. The only question is how to specify directory where to search for -name '*.zip' cause I need to look it for only in */public_html(only here)/*.zip?

Comment: You don't need to put this in a script. It's simple enough you can just type it on the command line whenever you need it.

Comment: @joanis how to search in public_html only folder...

Comment: @Marc not sure I understand what you're missing. My solution uses `*/public_html/*.zip` just like you did in your question, so it's only going to look where you want, no?

Comment: @melpomene thanks for pointing that out. @ Mihir proposed an edit to fix that, which I accepted, so it should now be fine with spaces in the file names.

Comment: @melpomene OK, sometimes it takes more tries than other times to get it right. Thanks for the complete space-in-name solution.